# No module named Appkit?

Tags: python-2.7, appkit

I have heard that appkit is included with PyObjC, so I installed with

```
$ sudo pip install pyobjc-core
$ sudo pip install pyobjc
```

And now when I go into Python:

```
>>> from AppKit import NSSpeechSynthesizer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named AppKit
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change AppKit to appkit, but you will still won't find NSSpeechSynthesizer there.

if you need NSSpeechSynthesizer, try this:

```
from Cocoa import NSSpeechSynthesizer

sp = NSSpeachSynthesizer.alloc().initWithVoice_(None) # use default voice
sp.startSpeakingString_("hello world")
```

Cocoa should be part of the PyObjC as far as I can understand.

source: http://code.activestate.com/lists/pythonmac-sig/23406/

Comment: I have tried what you say and I get an error:                Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Cocoa/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import AppKit
ImportError: No module named AppKit

Comment: Did you try changing AppKit to appkit?

well, apparently you need cocoa which is only available on Macs. http://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/install.html#requirements

Comment: Oh never mind. I changed appkit folder name to AppKit and the problem was solved!!! Thanks!

Comment: There is a typo in:  sp = NSSpeachSynthesizer.alloc().initWithVoice_(None) it should be sp = NSSpeechSynthesizer.alloc().initWithVoice_(None)